Dummy output in Ubuntu 24.04
I installed Ubuntu on top of Windows 11.
The sound is not working. I have searched all the forums with a similar problem and have not found any solution that can help me.
Hardware Information:
   Hardware Model: HUAWEI BOM-WXX9
   Graphics: AMD Radeon Graphics
   Firmware Version: 2.11
   OS Name: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
   OS Build: (null)
   OS Type: 64-bit
   GNOME Version: 46
   Windowing System: Wayland
   Kernel Version: Linux 6.8.0-35-generic

Please add more details about the hardware.

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              HUAWEI BOM-WXX9
Graphics:                                    AMD Radeon™ Graphics
Firmware Version:                           2.11
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-35-generic


What solutions have you already tried? 9 times out of 10, installing the pulseaudio volume control application (not the default volume controls that come with the system) and then going to the "configuration" tab and enabling one of the unavailable profiles or disabling and then enabling an existing profile usually works. Are you using HDMI for audio output?

i install/reinstall pulseaudio, changed sound configuration..
i use dinamics on my laptop, not hdmi..
trick in "configuration" also not working

I'm a layman. to avoid misunderstandings, I can execute some commands in the terminal according to your manual and give the result of their work
